# Hardcoding Javascript Constructor Parameter a no-no?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I'm playing around with Classes & Inheritance in Javascript but I'm not understanding one part of a constructors behavior. In my parent class, I `hard-coded` `bankAccountStatus` to the following value `Bank Account is Low`. Then I created a subclass called MemberStatus and defined the constructor parameters to be the same inputs of the parent class. However, if I try to change `bankAccountStatus` when I call `new MemberStatus` to something else, it won't take. I can of course change that to the parameter name to get it working, but I'm trying to understand the functionality of it. Is there anyway to change that value without converting it in the parent class to `this.bankAccountStatus = bankAccountStatus;`

```
class User {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, phone, bankAccountStatus){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.bankAccountStatus = 'Bank Account is Low';
  }
}

class MemberStatus extends User {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, phone, bankAccountStatus, vipStatus){
    super(firstName, lastName, phone, bankAccountStatus);
    this.vipStatus = vipStatus;
  }
}

let john = new MemberStatus('John', 'Doe', '555-123-4567', 'Bank Account is Wealthy', 'Gold');
console.log(john);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why bother adding it to the constructor of `User` if you're going to default it? Constructors of extended classes don't have to be the same:

```
class User {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, phone){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.bankAccountStatus = 'Bank Account is Low';
  }
}

class MemberStatus extends User {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, phone, bankAccountStatus, vipStatus){
    super(firstName, lastName, phone);
    this.bankAccountStatus = bankAccountStatus
    this.vipStatus = vipStatus;
  }
}

let john = new MemberStatus('John', 'Doe', '555-123-4567', 'Bank Account is Wealthy', 'Gold');
console.log(john);
```

Comment: Now that makes sense to me! I guess if you're not gonna make it "changeable" no need to make it a parameter. I appreciate the answer and learning moment :)

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> Is there anyway to change that value without converting it in the parent class to this.bankAccountStatus = bankAccountStatus

If you look at your constructors:

```
class User {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, phone, bankAccountStatus){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.bankAccountStatus = 'Bank Account is Low';
  }
}

class MemberStatus extends User {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, phone, bankAccountStatus, vipStatus){
    super(firstName, lastName, phone, bankAccountStatus);
    this.vipStatus = vipStatus;
  }
}
```

You are passing a string as your 4th user variable parameter, but you never do access it. If you'd like to give a default value to this.bankAccountStatus, you can put it in the parameters, like this:

```
class User {
  constructor(firstName, lastName, phone, bankAccountStatus = 'Bank Account is Low'){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.bankAccountStatus = bankAccountStatus;
  }
}
```

Good luck with your project!